# How to turn off USB Power completely on RPi B3+?

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

What I am trying to do is:
Programatically I want to switch on and off the USB power of the RPi B3+ or 4 models.
I know that I can put 0 in /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower but seems like it does not work as expected.

Let me show you what all things I have tried:

Check 1:

1. Connect USB device (In my case, its camera) to the Rpi
2. Fire command "lsusb" In the list,
3. I get my camera listed properly

Check 2:

1. The camera is connected and lsusb is showing the device
2. sudo vi /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower and put 0 in it and save the file
3. again lsusb
4. All the connected devices list is gone. Looks like its working

BUT:
When I put voltage meeter on the usb port(As showin in screenshot) , it shows same current flowing through the USB ports.
Refer attached screenshot below to understand this issue. 
Looking for the solution if anyone knows.
[image: Image showing steps and issue]

Comment: this might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165447/turning-off-power-to-usb-port-or-turn-off-power-to-entire-usb-subsystem

Comment: uhubctl worked, Thanks for sharing!